# Car shakes when braking: warped rotors or alignment?

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting, alignment

I have an 07 Chevy Impala and I'm trying to pinpoint the shaking that occurs when braking. Only shakes when braking slowly on highway. The whole car does shake pretty badly. I just put in a new set of tires also so it can't be that. Rotors or alignment?

Comment: Almost certainly rotors.

Comment: Did you use a torque wrench when you put on the new tires?  If the lugs were cranked on too tightly this can easily have been the cause.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of possibilities here, including:

1. bad tire
2. bent rim
3. unbalanced wheel
4. bad shock absorber mount
5. other suspension parts loose/worn/missing
6. steering rack
7. faulty wheel bearing
8. warped brake rotors
9. alignment problem

Although you have just put on new tires, there is still a possibility that they weren't properly balanced or that they were, but a wheel weight has come off since then.  Since most vibration issues stem from tire and wheel imbalance, check the first three on the above list first.

Because the problem only happens under braking at highway speeds (if I understand your description correctly), suspension parts are another good thing to check.  Worn or missing bushings, failing ball joints, etc. can all cause annoying vibrations.  Do a good visual inspection of the suspension, especially in the front.

Steering rack problems and wheel bearing failures usually make noises in addition to vibration, and they're both relatively easy to check.

Finally, warped rotors and alignment problems can cause this, but are, in my opinion, much less likely to be the culprit here.  If you have the equipment, it's not hard to check the runout on the rotors and determine if they're warped or not.

I'd suggest checking things in about the order I've listed.

Comment: great answer! I drove my grandpa's car yesterday and it shook violently while braking at highway speeds. Just last week he passed a safety inspection from a trusted mechanic so I was surprised that he could have missed something so bad. This will help me make sure I've got my bases covered when I tear into it.

Comment: I replaced both wheel bearings on the front, also replaced the two front struts. Rims are not bent

Comment: Alignment problems don't cause vibration. Very specifically, if a vehicle is out of alignment without any other problems, this will not cause vibration. If there are loose components in the front end, this might cause vibration. Loose front end parts will cause the alignment to go out but fixing the alignment with loose front end parts is impossible.

Comment: comprehensive answer, well laid out well done.

Comment: @vini_i: good point.  What I had in mind is that if the car is misaligned, this can and often does lead to uneven tire wear which causes vibration, but it's not the misalignment, per se, that causes the vibration.

Comment: I've heard it said that warped rotors are something of a myth, ISTR Carrol Shelby writing about it in fact. Certainly they're a phenomena that's often mentioned but I've never actually seen happen. Good answer though!

Comment: Just found a copy of the article, Carrol Smith not Shelby but on the same programme: http://www.stoptech.com/technical-support/technical-white-papers/-warped-brake-disc-and-other-myths

Comment: @JohnU: I've had it happen to me on a racetrack, but fortunately, I had a spare set of rotors. There's some debate about whether the cause is actually warping or just an uneven accumulation of brake pad residue. I'm not sure that's a distinction with a difference since the symptoms and fix are identical either way.

Comment: No probs! Back to the original post, there's varying qualities of balancing out there, my regular tyre place have a top quality balancer that can find imbalances in stuff that other shops have got "perfect". Same deal with their tracking bay, it's the best money can buy and they take their stuff seriously. They spend 10x more on their equipment than some shops do, and as a result tend to get about 10x better results.

Comment: This issue started when I changed my struts by the way.

Comment: @JohnU - had a Mazda 929 that suffered from this. Bad design - big, heavy car with flimsy rotors.

Comment: @Noah: If it started when you changed struts, that's definitely a good place to begin.  Make sure that everything is there and secure.  It's also probably a good idea to get the vehicle re-aligned if you haven't done so since changing the struts.

Comment: Well, I took it to a shop to get it aligned and was told my BOTH lower control arm new replacing (a little skeptical since I changed the driver side one) what do you guys think? They're saying they are swaying

Comment: @Edward you may want to add check for loose lug nuts to your list :')

Comment: @Noah what did they say was wrong with the control arms? there are two bushings and ball joint. They should be able to visually show you the problem if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be more of the problem on warped brake rotors or brake cylinders itself (had the shakiness once from the 2nd one as brake caliper had gone and cylinder was touching the rotor).

I do not think this can be unbalanced wheel as you would feel the effect of unbalanced wheel without braking on highway speeds.

Also, there was suggestion that shock absorbers are defective, but I would rule that out too, as I have driven car which had faulty shock absorbers and you couldn't feel it as shaking when braking, moreof feeling like being on a boat that goes up and down alot.

Comment: I've had bad wheel wobble (as in, unbalanced wheel oscillating) which was made much much worse by worn shocks unable to control the movement. New shocks actually cured it without rebalancing the wheel.

Comment: Well, in that case it is still good idea to balance the wheel, as it is still too much unneeded extra work for shocks

Comment: that's true but the tyres are 37x12.50 mud terrains with various chunks taken out by rocks so they ain't easy to balance and never stay balanced for long.

Comment: Well, that changes everything, didn't know you had such tires

Answer (score 1):

Classic symptom of warpped brake rotors.   Logic say if it only happens when braking, it's a brake problem.

Answer (score 0):

My prime candidate would be shock absorbers being defective. Without the damping effect of shock absorbers you are basically bouncing on your springs. Every little bump or roadway imperfection would be felt. It would be very noticeable when braking for the simple reason of your tires having intermittent with the road. One of the things that shock absorbers do help the tires maintain contact with the road surface for improved cornering, braking effectiveness, and overall vehicle stability.

Comment: The car doesn't have any of the other symptoms associated with shocks though.Doesn't shake when moving only when breaking from a high rate of speed (70MPH) and it's so bad I shave to left my foot off the break so I don't tear the wheels off! I had my break pads changed so I'll check my rotors and see

Comment: Stopping at a high rate of speed.....Maybe ABS system kicking in. Warped rotors would be noticeable any  time the wheels are spinning.

Answer (score -1):

Control arms will do that if you have a bad bushing, you should have it inspected by a shop, some people on the internet dont know what they are talking about